# Swift: Unsatisfying constraints (auto layout) after tableView reloadSections

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

my problem looks like a weird behavior to me. I'm using Swift and iOS9+.

I've set up an `UIViewController` in storyboard with some views and a `tableview`. (Views are vertically above the tableview) All is set up properly with autolayout, no warnings and the `UIViewController` displays correctly.

In `viewDidLoad()` I request some table view data from an API and call `tableView.reloadSections()` after getting the response, the section fades correctly.

If I tap on a button in the section header, another view controller is presented where I can filter the requested data. After setting the filter, the view controller dismisses and the `refreshVitalSigns(...)` is called in the delegate.
Then again, I want to reload the table view section to only show the filtered data. When I call `reloadSections()` again, I get a lot of unsatisfying constraint warnings and the view is messed up, and I don't know why??????
With `reloadData()` everything works, but I only want to reload the section.

FYI: After requesting the API data, you have to scroll to see the whole table view content. If I scroll first, to see the whole content, and filter afterwards, also the `reloadSections()` works well! Obviously, it should also work without scrolling first...

Do you have any idea why this strange behavior happens?

I'm greatful for every hint!!!

Best

```
class JMProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    /// Table view top spacing
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopSpacing: NSLayoutConstraint!

    /// Table view
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    /// Attention view
    @IBOutlet var attentionView: JMAttentionView?

    var vitalSigns: [Items] = []
    var data: [Items] = []

    ...


    // View did load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        // Table view row height
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

        // Register custom tableview header/footer views and cells
        ...

        // Get table view data
        let patientId = ...
        getData(patientId)
    }


    /**
     Get data

     - parameter patientId: Patient ID
     */
    func getData(patientId: Int) {

        // Request
        APIController.sharedInstance.getData(patientId: patientId) { response in

            // Result handling
            switch response {
            case .Success(let result):
                // Update vital signs
                self.vitalSigns = result
                self.data = result

                // Reload data
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }


    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Set constraints depending on view's visibility
        if let view = attentionView {
            if view.hidden {
                tableViewTopSpacing.constant = 0
            } else {
                tableViewTopSpacing.constant = view.bounds.height
            }
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Navigation

    // Preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // Data segue
        if segue.identifier == SegueIdentifier.JMVitalSignsSegue.rawValue {
            let vsvc = segue.destinationViewController as! JMVitalSignsViewController
            vsvc.delegate = self
        }
    }

}


// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension JMProfileViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    // Number of sections in table view
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }


    // Height for header in section
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return section == 0 ? 0 : UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


    // Estimated height for header in section
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return section == 0 ? 0 : 27.0
    }


    // View for header in section
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        switch section {
        case 0:
            // First section without header
            return nil
        case 1:
            // Configure header
            let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier.JMTitleButtonHeaderView.rawValue) as! JMTitleButtonHeaderView
            header.configure(NSLocalizedString("vitalSigns", comment: ""), buttonTarget: self, buttonImage: UIImage(named: "ic_filter_dark"), buttonAction: #selector(parameterButtonTapped(_:)))
            return header
        default:
            // Configure header
            let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier.JMTitleButtonHeaderView.rawValue) as! JMTitleButtonHeaderView
            header.configure(NSLocalizedString("others", comment: ""))
            return header
        }
    }


    /**
     Vital signs button tapped
     */
    func parameterButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        // Show vital signs view controller
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SegueIdentifier.JMVitalSignsSegue.rawValue, sender: self)
    }


    // Number of rows in section
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var rows = 0

        switch section {
        case 0:
            // Diagnosis
            rows = 1
            break
        case 1:
            // Vital signs
            rows = data.count > 0 ? data.count : 1
            break
        case 2:
            // Others
            rows = 3
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        return rows
    }


    // Cell for row at indexpath
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier.JMSubtitleImageRightDetailCell.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JMSubtitleImageRightDetailCell
            // Configure cell
            ...
            return cell
        case 1:
            if data.count > 0 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier.JMTitleThreeLabelsSubtitleCell.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JMTitleThreeLabelsSubtitleCell
                // Configure cell
                let item = data[indexPath.row]
                cell.configure(item.caption, unit: item.unit, values: item.values)
                cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
                return cell
            } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier.JMBasicCell.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath)
                // Configure cell
                cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("noData", comment: "")
                cell.selectionStyle = .None
                return cell
            }
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier.JMBasicCell.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JMDefaultCell
            ...
            return cell
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - JMVitalSignsViewControllerDelegate

extension JMProfileViewController: JMVitalSignsViewControllerDelegate {

    /**
     Refresh vital signs
     */
    func refreshVitalSigns(selectedItems: [Items]) {
        print("Refresh vital signs")
        var data: [Items] = []
        for item in selectedItems {
            for vitalItem in vitalSigns {
                if item.match == vitalItem.match {
                    data.append(vitalItem)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        self.data = data

        // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
//        tableView.beginUpdates()
//        tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
//        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: may be the updateViewConstraints function is causing the problem. just guessed

Comment: thanks for your guess! I commented the updateViewConstraints function out, but it makes no difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a workaround.

I changed the `UIViewController` into a `UITableViewController` and added every custom `UIView` in the TableViewHeader (NOT Section header) with auto layout.

Now it works!